# How can I catch *all* exceptions in Application_BeginRequest?

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception

I'm trying to catch a specific exception which is occurring in my Application_BeginRequest.

So far I've been totally unable to catch the exception to see what's going wrong, but the user sees a 500 Internal Server Error.  All other exceptions are logged with Elmah but in this instance, Elmah is not logging it.

```
try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_BLUECOAT_VIA"]))
        {
            string original = Request.QueryString.ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.Path + "?" + original.Replace(Server.UrlEncode("amp;"), "&"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
    }
```

If I change catch to catch(Exception ex) the exception is NOT caught and the error still occurs.

If I comment out the code inside the try block, the page loads fine with no errors, so the error is definitely occurring within the try block, but somehow throwing an exception which cannot be caught using a try/catch block.

Comment: I'd suspect something amiss in your `web.config` (or, less likely, in the core machine config) - if it can't decipher a sane configuration, it won't ever get around to running your (or ELMAHs) code.

Comment: The error is definitely occurring directly in that try block. If I delete the contents of the try block the exception doesn't occur.

Comment: I suspect the error is the RewritePath method

Answer (score 1):

Try `Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();` in the body of your catch block if other attempts aren't working.

You can also  handle uncaught exceptions using the Application_Error event in the same Globals class.

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){
      Exception exception = Server.GetLastError(); 
 }
```

Comment: If I let the exception occur then Application_Error never actually fires, so this method will not work for me :(

Comment: Try Server.GetLastError() in your catch block

Comment: Actually just realised that even catch {} isn't catching it. I must have been testing on the wrong site when I thought that was working. Have updated my question accordingly.